Name of this movie about a bunch of people trapped in an elevator or room?
I saw this movie perhaps around 2010-2011 but I can't remember the name or much about it. But it's been bugging me for the past week, and I just can't remember it's name.
The film was about people trapped in a room or elevator or something. And there's a maintenance guy behind it (I think).
The most memorable scene was one of the guys had his toe cut off.
It's definitely not Saw, Elevator, or Devil I know that much. Also, I think the movie title began with "Saint" or "St." And I think that was in reference to the apartment complex or motel or something that it took place in. I can't find any reference to it anywhere in Google.

What does 'ages ago' mean? - it will make it easier for us if we can rule out movies that are more recent.

A few years back... Around 2010-2011, maybe. I doubt that it would've been made after 2011, since I rented it on DVD.

Probably should rule out Cube, Penny Dreadful (the movie, not the recent series) and Hostel. Although all feature people trapped (weird elevator structure, car, warehouse) who lose toes, none are actually in apartment buildings. How many people, roughly, and can you name some of their demises or fates?

I honestly can't remember. It was a group of people... So 5-8 maybe. If I could remember all these details I probably would've found something on Google...

Four Stories of St. Julian (2010)?

YES THANK YOU! FOUR STORIES IF SAINT JULIAN! THATS IT!

@pori add it as an answer.

@Pingu: Can you accept Pori's answer below? To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks!

Four Stories of St. Julian  (2010)

Four strangers become trapped in the elevator of St. Julian-a
  decrepit, inner-city building. One of the four is an assassin.

